# How do I find the parametric representation of the $t_1\vec{u}+t_2\vec{v}+\vec{w}$ for a plane passing through these three points?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

The points this plane must go through are as follows: $(1,1,0), (-2,0,2),$ and $(2,1,1)$. I don't understand how to approach this problem.

Comment: It's simple. $t_1[(2,1,1)-(1,1,0)]+t_2[(2,1,1)-(-2,0,2)]+(2,1,1)$

Comment: Does it matter which points you choose? Like if you switched the $(2,1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$ then would it still be true>

Comment: Yes, it still would be true. Order of points doesn't matter here. We just need 2 linearly independent vectors, and a point belonging to the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system of parametric equations of the plane is a linear combination of the points that belong to it, i.e.
\begin{align}
 p(t_1,t_2) =
 t_1
\Bigg(
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0
 \end{bmatrix}
-
\underbrace{
 \begin{bmatrix}
  2 \\
  1 \\
  1
 \end{bmatrix}
}_{\text{reference}}
\Bigg)
 +
 t_2
\Bigg(
 \begin{bmatrix}
  -2 \\
  0 \\
  2
 \end{bmatrix}
-
\underbrace{
 \begin{bmatrix}
  2 \\
  1 \\
  1
 \end{bmatrix}
}_{\text{reference}}
\Bigg)
 +
\underbrace{
 \begin{bmatrix}
  2 \\
  1 \\
  1
 \end{bmatrix}
}_{\text{reference}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Thed plane has the equation $$\vec{x}=[1;1;0]+\alpha[-3;-1,2]+\beta[1;0;1]$$ where $$\alpha,\beta$$ are the parameters.